# Need to group data on multiple columns in pandas and display the bar graph

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I have a rally data set which has below columns sorted by sprint number.

```
Feature ID User Story ID Sprint Points
01          101            1      3
01          102            1      5
02          103            1      2
03          104            1      5
01          105            2      5
01          106            2      2
04          107            2      2
```

I want to show data for each feature which will show userstories, sprint and user story points so that I know how many user stories are under each feature, in which sprint it is starting and ending. Basically like a roadmap of feature.

Any help would be appreciated

I tried groupby in pandas and the bar graph is not coming as expected for me

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your dataframe before display the bar graph. What you expect is not clear (x-axis, y-axis) however you can try the code below and adapt it to your expected output:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Sprint', 'User Story ID'],
                     columns='Feature ID', values='Points', 
                     aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

for sprint, subdf in df1.groupby(level='Sprint'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    subdf.droplevel('Sprint').plot.bar(title=f'Sprint {sprint}', rot=0, ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]